# create table combining table with fixed records and table with dynamically added records

Tags: sql-server

I have asked this over at Stackoverflow but with no luck :-(

I have two tables. One, tableX, that gets values from a PLC and one, tableY, that hold text strings. I need to populate a third table with rows of only the records that have a specific value, 1, in tableX and combined with their respective text labels from tableY

tableX has columns mapped to all relevant tags in the PLC plus a timestamp column getdate() ie when a tag in the PLC shift to 1 it will create a record in tableX with a timestamp and a 1 in the corresponding cell.

tableX

| timestamp | INFO00_1 | INFO00_2 | INFO00_3 | INFO00_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| getdate() | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

tableY has two columns no and name. Here records consist of the text string and no. The no column is also a text. like this.

tableY

| no | name |
| --- | --- |
| INFO00_1 | some text string |
| INFO00_0 | some text string |

I am faily new to SQL so I bear with me. I think that i can use a stored procedure to create a temp table that gets updated whenever there is a new record in tableX and then use this table to populate  a tableZ adding the no eg INFO00_1 to the record. like this

tableZ

| no | timestamp | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| INFO00_1 | getdate() | some text string |

Hopefully this makes sense and is doable, otherwise I am in trouble

Comment: Are you sure you need a table? Would a View do instead? Anyway, please see [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/4511) for query-writing questions.

Comment: @vonPryz Thanks for the link. I am not sure about much when it comes to SQL :-) as I understand it a view is  temporary and data only exist when queried? if this is the case I need a table since I have some regulations (FDA) that I need to satisfy.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include regulatory requirements and whatnot there too. Comments are ephemeral, and not suitable for details.

Comment: Have a look at this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1):

Made it work with a little help from google and some fiddling

https://dbfiddle.uk/_8Vj2pgP

Question closed